# Android Studio : Kotlin autocomplete not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin

*Kotlin* autocomplete in android studio isn't showing all available suggestion.

The same code snippet in *Java* suggests `setErrorEnabled()`

[Kotlin autocomplete snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAxUJ.png)

I tried restarting IDE, invalidate cache but still don't work as it used to do in Java.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textPasswordInput.isErrorEnabled = true`. Kotlin converts Java getters and setters into Kotlin properties. It still allows you to call `setErrorEnabled` but since the property syntax is preferred, it doesn’t include the setter method in the autocomplete. Notice your use of the setter is highlighted with a warning.